# Robot Framework, AngularJSLibrary - No module named 'Selenium2Library.locators'

Tags: python, angularjs, robotframework

I am setting up a new machine on Windows Server 2016 to run some existing Robot Framework tests of an Angular application. As it's a new machine I decided to move from Python 2 to 3.  I've installed all the dependencies I should need...

```
> pip list
certifi (2017.11.5)
chardet (3.0.4)
idna (2.6)
pip (9.0.1)
pip-autoremove (0.9.0)
requests (2.18.4)
robotframework (3.0.2)
robotframework-angularjs (0.0.6)
robotframework-extendedselenium2library (0.9.1)
robotframework-pabot (0.43)
robotframework-requests (0.4.7)
robotframework-selenium2library (3.0.0)
robotframework-seleniumlibrary (3.0.0)
robotremoteserver (1.1)
selenium (3.8.0)
setuptools (28.8.0)
urllib3 (1.22)'
```

When I run my tests (both in Jenkins and on the command line) I get the following error

```
Error in file 'C:\apps\Jenkins\workspace\RF_RunUITests\common.robot': Importing test library 'AngularJSLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium2Library.locators'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\apps\buildTools\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\AngularJSLibrary\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Selenium2Library.locators import ElementFinder
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\apps\buildTools\Python36-32\python36.zip
  C:\apps\buildTools\Python36-32\DLLs
  C:\apps\buildTools\Python36-32\lib
  C:\apps\buildTools\Python36-32
  C:\apps\buildTools\Python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

I have a very similar problem when I switch to the 'ExtendedSelenium2Library' - which also has support for Angular apps.

```
Error in file 'C:\apps\Jenkins\workspace\RF_RunUITests\common.robot': Importing test library 'ExtendedSelenium2Library' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium2Library.keywords'
```

I've done a number of searches but I have not found anything to help.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling!

The test suite I've been focusing on for testing purposes pulls in a resource that references the two following libraries

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library    implicit_wait=5    timeout=5
Library           AngularJSLibrary
Library           String
Library           DateTime
Library           Collections
```

I don't really know Python very well so I am struggling to know what to do next.

Anyone got any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: I think the answer is already right in front of you: these libraries do not support Python 3.x and only 2.7.x.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the libraries you are using haven't been updated to use the new version of SeleniumLibrary. They are trying to import modules that no longer exist, or exist under another name.

You'll either need to upgrade the libraries yourself, or switch back to using version 2.x of Selenium2Library.